# how to use getBytes:length?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cbperipheral

```
- (int) compareCBUUID:(CBUUID *) UUID1 UUID2:(CBUUID *)UUID2 {

    char b1[128];
    char b2[128];
    [UUID1.data getBytes:b1];
    [UUID2.data getBytes:b2];
    if (memcmp(b1, b2, UUID1.data.length) == 0)return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

How I can convert above method to use getBytes:length in above method ?

Thanks

Comment: A straightforward reading of your question has an absolutely trivial answer, suggesting somethings missing. So what have you tried and why didn't it do what you require? If you edit your question and provide these additional details somebody may be able to help you with whatever your actual problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so hard? Just:

```
- (int)compareCBUUID:(CBUUID *) UUID1 UUID2:(CBUUID *)UUID2 {
    return (int)(UUID1 == UUID2 || [UUID1 isEqual:UUID2]);
}
```

Comment: Does `CBUUID` implement `-isEqual` in a useful way?

Comment: Thanks @cy-4AH. It helps me alot.